# How to send values during a button is pressed/holding

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to send values ​​as long as the button is pressed. At the moment a value is only sent with every click. Below-mentioned is the current code:

my_script.js

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#left').click(function() {
    var left = 1
        $.ajax({
            url: '/stream',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { left:left }
    });
  });
```

my_form.html

```
<form>
<input type="button" value="LEFT" id="left" />
</form>
```

my_app.py

```
print request.forms.get("left")
```

Comment: So what have you tried to overcome the problem? You to have some sort of handler that registers that your mouse is down.

Comment: Take a look at the [mousedown](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/) event.

Answer (score 2):

Use `mousedown` Event to start interval.

```
var interval = null;

$('#left').bind("mousedown", function() {
  interval = setInterval(function() {
     /* do some stuuff every 10 ms*/
  }), 10);
});
```

And `mouseup` Event to clear interval.

```
$('#left').bind("mouseup", function() {
  clearInterval(interval);
});
```

Comment: That will still only trigger one time.

Comment: Thx for quick answer but unfortunately it does not work. I have also to click for every '''post/submit'''

Comment: Why `mousedown` and not a normal `click` event?

Comment: Because we want to send data while user is Holding mouses button.

Comment: @M1K1O - very true! The click event only fires when the user releases the mouse button. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a global variable, here `pressed`. Set it `true` on `mousedown`, and `false` on `mouseup`. After setting it `true`, call a method like this:

```
var pressed = false;
$('#left').on("mousedown", function(){
  pressed= true;
  SendDataIfPressed();
});

$('#left').on("mouseup", function(){
  pressed = false;
});

function SendDataIfPressed() {
    if (pressed) {
        var left = 1
        $.ajax({
            url: '/stream',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { left:left },
            complete: function() { SendDataIfPressed(); }
        });
    }
}
```

Instead of calling `SendDataIfPressed` in ajax' complete handler, you can also set a timeout like `setTimeout(SendDataIfPressed, TimeInMS);`.

Answer (score 1):

What you would need to do is add another event handler for the [`mouseup` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseup):

> The mouseup event is fired when a pointing device button (usually a mouse button) is released over an element.

What you would want to do is trigger a loop once the button is clicked and stop the loop when you detect a `mouseup` event:

```
var do_loop = true; // initialize the flag to execute the request loop

// mousedown is used because a normal click event is only 
// fired when the user releases the mouse button.
$('#left').on('mousedown', function(){
  do_loop = true; // ensure the loop will be executed once button is clicked
  make_ajax_request();
});

$('#left').on('mouseup', function(){
  do_loop = false; // toggle the boolean flag to stop the loop from iterating.
});

function make_ajax_request(){
  var self = this;
  $.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(){
      // only if the loop is activated will we make another request
      if ( do_loop ){ 
        self.make_ajax_request();
      }
    }
  });
}
```

The `make_ajax_request` function is the main part of my example. Inside the function, as soon as the request has completed it checks to see if the `do_loop` boolean flag is set to true - if so, the function is called again and the loop continues. If at some stage, the `mouseup` event is caught, the boolean flag will be switched to false and the `make_ajax_request` function will not actually execute the request hence ending the loop.